# How can I open Openshift - port 9111 (grpc app)

Tags: java, openshift, grpc, minishift

I have grpc app(client and server) which is working on localhost fine, but I have problem in MiniShift. Each app run in different pod. Problem is that client cant connect to server:

```
java.net.ConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused
at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.throwConnectException(Errors.java:124) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.28.0.jar!/:1.28.0]
at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.unix.Socket.finishConnect(Socket.java:243) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.28.0.jar!/:1.28.0]
at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.doFinishConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:672) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.28.0.jar!/:1.28.0]
at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:649) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.28.0.jar!/:1.28.0]
at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.epollOutReady(AbstractEpollChannel.java:529) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.28.0.jar!/:1.28.0]
at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:465) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.28.0.jar!/:1.28.0]
at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.28.0.jar!/:1.28.0]
at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.28.0.jar!/:1.28.0]
at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.28.0.jar!/:1.28.0]
at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.28.0.jar!/:1.28.0]
```

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_242]

I tried connection between pods, but only port 80 and 443 are opened. Rest of ports return Connection Refused.

How can I open port 9111 (where my grpc java app is running) ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'll need to create a **service** with **NodePort** type.

NodePorts are type of services that open a port on each cluster machine and can redirect traffic - TCP/UDP - to your applications. For this, you'll need **administration** privileges with the use **system:admin** or give to a user of your choice... for example:

```
oc adm policy add-cluster-role-to-user cluster-admin matko
```

Unfortunally Openshift is based in Kubernetes, and Kubernetes by default only allow node ports to be in the range **30000-32767**.

Your aplication will still hearing in 9111, but to reach from outside the cluster we only had the ports I wrote above.

Find the application service and edit:

```
oc edit svc mysql
```

Then, change the **Type** to **NodePort** and choose a port - or get a random one:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    name: mysql
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 3036
      nodePort: 30036
      name: http
  selector:
    name: mysql
```

This is for explanation once, never expose the database on the internet.